# ReactJS: Looking to improve my dynamic fields building component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-hooks

I'm relatively new with React functional components and I'm trying to build a system that builds forms out of an array of objects. It works so far, but I feel like I am missing something. Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import "./DynamicForm.css";

function DynamicForm(props) {
    const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState([
        { name: "first_name", type: "text", value: "" },
        { name: "last_name", type: "text", value: "" },
        { name: "phone", type: "tel", value: "" },
        { name: "email", type: "email", value: "" },
        { name: "date_of_birth", type: "date", value: "" },
        { name: "language", type: "select", options: ['en', 'es'], value: "" },
    ])

    const handleChange = (index, value) => {
        let newFormFields = [...formFields];
        newFormFields[index].value = value;
        setFormFields(newFormFields);
    }

    const builtForm = (
        <div>
            {formFields.map((field, index) => {
                return (
                    <div class="col-md-3" index={index}>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">{field.name}</label>
                        <input placeholder="" type={field.type} class="form-control" value={field.value} onChange={(e) => handleChange(index, e.target.value)} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )

    return (
        <div>
            <section>
                {builtForm}
            </section>
        </div>);
}

export default DynamicForm;
```

Note: I cut the code to the core to improve readability.

Isn't it a bit too simple? Every time I enter a new characters in one of the generated inputs, the whole form with all its fields re-renders again, am I right? Should I use other hooks or design it otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about creating components dynamically like this without having the entire component update but here are some thoughts.

First up, in JSX `class` should be `className`. `class` is already a keyword in JavaScript so we use `className`, I believe this is what it is called in the virtual dom which is what you are actually editing/creating there.

Second, provide the key prop to components created by a loop. This helps with what is called [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html). Helping react recognize what components actually need updating. In your case, your fields all have a unique `name` prop, so you might change the div inside the map to this:

```js
return (
    <div key={field.name} className='col-md-3' index={index}>
        ...
    </div>
);
```

[Never use the index of the loop for the key](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys).

Next, for this approach, to avoid the rerender of all inner components, I would want to use the `useMemo` hook to cache the elements. The issue is that you would create the component in a loop, which goes against "[rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level)".

In the end, my approach would be to create a separate component for each field rather than creating them via a loop. However, I'd love to hear how some more experienced people might approach this to achieve the dynamic approach.